# SonarQube: denial of service for regex pattern due to polynomial runtime backtracking

Tags: regex, security, sonarqube, denial-of-service

I am using a regex pattern to validate an email. SonarQube is giving "Make sure the regex used here,which is vulnerable to polynomial runtime due to backtracking, cannot lead to denial of service".

The code looks like below

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.+@.+(\\.[^.]+)++$");
return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
```

Tried some patterns but could'nt get desired result.

It is very important that **current behaviour of pattern matching should not break.**

Please help me with this regex pattern improvisation that should not break my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, it is failing when I pass "no@period" as email

Comment: Actually no@period should not be a valid email, but while testing it shows as valid email.

Comment: Then use `^[^@]+@[^.]+(?>\\.[^.]+)+$`

Comment: Thanks it works, hope it is also SonarQube compliant.

Comment: Sonar always generates this warning when you quantify groups already containing quantified patterns, so I doubt you can  refactor the regex to a version that will be compliant with Sonar. You can safely use `"^[^@]+@[^.]+(?:\\.[^.]+)+$"` and turn the warning off.